# I cannot retrieve the data from MySQL Workbench 8.0 by using JSP as my platform via apache tomcat server. Why is that?

Tags: mysql, database, jsp, tomcat8

I've been trying to get my code to work but the code cannot retrieve the data from the database. The database editor that I am using is the MySQL Workbench 8.0. I am using Apache Tomcat server to open the jsp file via browser. The code works and it opens on the web browser but it doesn't show the data that i have created in the database workbench. Is there something wrong with the code that i am using or is it the database editor that i am using ?

```
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>

<%
String id = request.getParameter("id");
String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String dbName = "users";
String userId = "root";
String password = "mysqluser";

try {
Class.forName(driverName);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;
%>
<h2 align="center"><font><strong>Retrieve data from database in jsp</strong></font></h2>
<table align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="1">
<tr>

</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#A52A2A">
<td><b>id</b></td>
<td><b>name</b></td>
<td><b>profession</b></td>

</tr>
<%
try{ 
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl+dbName, userId, password);
statement=connection.createStatement();
String sql ="SELECT * FROM users";

resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
while(resultSet.next()){
%>
<tr bgcolor="#DEB887">

<td><%=resultSet.getString("id") %></td>
<td><%=resultSet.getString("name") %></td>
<td><%=resultSet.getString("profession") %></td>


</tr>

<% 
}

} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
</table>
```